# Ubuntu installation error for 13.04 and 12.04

Tags: system-installation, ubiquity

During the GUI installation, I get an error box with a series of `???????` when it begins the installation. This has happened for both 13.04 and 12.04 flavors. It loads the "**Try Ubuntu**" but not the installation. The notebook itself recently had an error with its previous Windows OS where it would only boot straight to the BIOS and not boot anything. Suggestions on what the issue is?

Comment: Did you check if your downloaded ISO images were not corrupt?

Answer (score 1):

I had also similar installation problem, but later on I had found that that problem was actually in my hard disk drive. It was locked. In "Try Ubuntu" format your hard disk. Maybe this solves your problem!